# Is using PHPs password_hash function worth the performance hit?

Tags: php, security, passwords

I have read that using `password_hash()` is one of the best way of generating passwords using php. I have ran some tests and this function is really hard on the CPU. Is it worth it vs a salted `sha1()` method?

I don't mind using it, but there might be a login every 10 seconds or so I'm worried it will slow the server down.

I set up a loop to generate 1000 `password_hash()` values and the server timed out after 30 seconds. In comparison I generated 1000 salted `sha1()` passwords and it was instant.

Is the performance hit worth it?

Comment: Slow password hashing is a good thing. Also SHA1 is broken and obsolete and has been for a while now. You shouldn't even be considering it.

Comment: yes im aware of it, but is the huge performance hit worth the gain?

Comment: You don't use password_hash() for logging in; you use it for new passwords/password changes..... do you have a new password/password change every 10 seconds, or simply a login every 10 seconds?

Comment: Totes worth it. You really shouldn't use your own salts on password hashes and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security.

Comment: no it will just be a login. the exiting hash will be stored in the database. Do i not need to rehash the input in order to compare it against the value in the DB?

Comment: No, when a user logs in, you use password_verify() to compare their entered password against the hash that you have stored on the database

Comment: I still got a timeout using password_verify() surely it would have to rehash the raw password in order to make a comparison. is it not quicker to just hash it first and then perform the sql query?

Comment: Simply hash it, and you'll get a different value, because every generated hash has a unique salt.... you don't simply create a new hash and compare, you need to be able to use the same salt that was generated for the original hash when you verify

Comment: Yes, those methods are hard on the CPU and take long to execute - that is desired! You don't want people who got their hands on your db to easily be able to "decrypt" your users' passwords. The question I ask myself: If you have that many logins, maybe get another server/a stronger one to handle your requests or overthink your program flow - maybe let users stay logged in for longer?

Comment: MarkBaker - ah yes good point i didnt think of this at all. The existing setup is using a fixed salt with sha1 so they are just compared this way. kingkero - i agree. not an easy task at the moment for me, but ill go ahead with this and try find a way to assign more juice. one of these days ill get a dedicated server!

Comment: @DanHastings - Remember to make your fixed salt long enough and random, as even a salted hash can be vulnerable against rainbow table attacks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point of protecting passwords in the database is to give you some time after a database compromise to notice you've been compromised, lock accounts, and issue notice to your users that they need to change passwords if they re-used them elsewhere.

Simple hashing such as salted-SHA1 barely fulfills this purpose any more. With hardware-accelerated brute-force it is feasible for an attacker to obtain a lot of the passwords before you've had much chance to do anything about it.

“Worth it” always varies for every application and its threat model, and there are certainly other approaches to handling passwords/authentication that can be justified, but approaches like `password_hash` are considered the baseline standard practice for web applications, something that today you have to justify *not* using.

And because users do—alas—re-use passwords across sites, skimping on hashing means that in the event of database compromise it is not just your own site's security that is at risk. So even if your service contains nothing especially sensitive, you have some degree of responsibility for others.

Comment: @Dan Hastings - If the load on your server is too heavy, then you can reduce the cost factor. Even if the BCrypt calculation takes only a milli-second, this is ways better than if an attacker can calculate [4Giga SHA-1/s](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat/#performance).

Comment: As per http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3959/recommended-of-iterations-when-using-pkbdf2-sha256/3993#3993 , you want your hash to take about 250 ms on your server at this time

Comment: bcrypt even at cost 5 is still quite safe from brute-forcing: http://passwords12.at.ifi.uio.no/Jeremi_Gosney_Password_Cracking_HPC_Passwords12.pdf (those tests were done with test 5).